# How can I sign this Google CLA and get my PR accepted without having to re-commit my changes?

Tags: git, github, google-workspace, authoring, commit

I fixed an issue for an open source project and am required to sign [this](https://cla.developers.google.com/) CLA before the PR can be merged. A repository owner has approved the PR, but the CLA isn't showing as signed.

#### Details

I use Google Apps on my domain; it's an older, grandfathered version that is free, but hobbled. I sign in to my domain email with user@mydomain.tld, and my "Google account" is user@mydomain.tld.

However, my github email is gituser@mydomain.tld. `git config --global --list` initially had my email as gituser@mydomain.tld, so I have commits in the PR with my github email. I later enabled email privacy and updated my git config to reflect it with `1234+someuser@noreply.github.com` (I've verified that my anonymized email is correct between my github profile and the git config).

I signed in and signed the CLA, but googlebot doesn't detect that the CLA has been signed, because user@mydomain.tld who signed the CLA (my Google Account email), didn't commit the code - gituser@mydomain.tld did (my GitHub email).

I tried to solve this by adding user@mydomain.tld to my github profile, verifying the email, and making user@mydomain.tld the primary email - then "updating the contact info" on the CLA. googlebot still doesn't accept the CLA as signed by the committing author.

I can't create a Google Account with gituser@mydomain.tld, because Google wants me to create a new *Google* account, i.e. a gmail account.

I can't add an alternate email to my existing Google Account, because my Google Account is hobbled as an old (free) Google Apps account that never upgraded to paid.

---

How can I sign the CLA, commit the code, and get googlebot to see the two as linked?